# Are 2016 Republican candidates allowed to attend debates not sponsored by the RNC?

Tags: united-states, debate, republican-primary, rnc

In the 2012 U.S. Presidential campaign, there were a very large number of Republican primary debates.  After the election was over, the Republican National Committee (RNC) concluded that that there were too many debates, and that this had a damaging effect on whoever emerges as the party nominee.  So they decided that in 2016, the only Republican primary debates would be the ones sponsored by the RNC, rather than having candidates choose which debates they wanted to attend like last time, and there would be many fewer debates, about one debate per month starting this August.

My question is, how is this decision enforced?  What stops a Republican candidate from attending a debate that is not sponsored by the RNC?  And if nothing is stopping that from happening, are there any organizations or news outlets that are trying to host non-RNC-approved debates?

Comment: I believe it's enforced like any private gathering. Those that are invited may attend, and those that aren't invited may be blocked at the door.

Comment: @DA I'm not talking about candidates attending RNC-sponsored debates without being invited.  I'm talking about candidates attending debates which they're invited to but are not sponsored by the RNC.  In 2012, candidates were able to attend debates that weren't sponsored by the RNC.  But the RNC doesn't want them to do that this time.

Comment: That may come down to a state-by-state issue. I believe each state party gets to decide who or who can not be on the ballot under their party affiliation. I suppose at the national level, they could declare than any republican wanting to debate without party permission would risk losing the party affiliation on the ballot in some (all?) states. Interesting question.

Comment: @DA. I just found an article from last December on this: http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/dec/7/rnc-cap-on-2016-presidential-debates-could-give-ri/?page=all "As it stands, the RNC plans to penalize candidates that participate in unsanctioned events by leaving them out of sanctioned ones."  I'm not sure how that would work, since for legal reasons the networks and not the RNC get to choose who are in the debates.  I'm also not sure whether the RNC has finalized this rule since the time the article was published.

Comment: I don't understand: can't the party just expel those who violate their own policy?

Comment: @Lohoris - not really. Unlike Communist Party of the Soviet Union, there's no centrally enforced membership that one can be expelled from.

Comment: @DVK so, a party is some sort of association, where you can sign, and once you are in you can't be kicked off no matter what you do? Seriously?

Comment: @Lohoris - You don't "sign" into a party. You merely - optionally - declare a party affiliation when registering to vote (which entitles you to vote in that party's primary in non-open-primary state; and can't be revoked excepy by you yourself). Mind you, there are probably some sorts of local activist/leadership associations that you get memberships in, but they are at a level more constrained than actual "Party".

Comment: @Lohoris - when you see words like "Committee", that's where you get into real membership territory